# Windows touch events in web page

Tags: javascript, touch

I'm trying to figure out how to add event listeners for windows touch events (like a big touch screen monitor, not mobile) in Windows 7 and can't seem to make things like touchstart touchend etc. trigger in any browser.  Do these events just not fire in a browser like they do on an iPad?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, those events are included only in some mobile navigators (not all, see http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html ). I don't think you can handle them on a standard browser like ff/ie/chrome. You'll have to use mousedown & cie.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the v2 branch of hammer.js http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/v2/, it's a nice touch event abstraction layer for iOS, Android, BlackBerry and also includes support for Windows touch events.